# Facebook. Fan page. Wall. Pictures

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have some problems with Facebook Graph API and want to ask some short questions.

**Firstly**. Is there any method to post multiple images in **single wall page post** using API? Any method? I want take some photos, text description and say to facebook through API: "I need your wall post with this data". After search I did not find any chance to do it.

**Secondary**. I can add single photo with description to page wall (**edge** /{pageID}/photos), but I **can not edit** through API (**edge** /{photoID}). Interesting fact - facebook answers to API photo edit call with message "success: true", but nothing happens! Image **stays unchanged**. Maybe anyone knows why?

Thank you for your future advices and your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can´t post multiple pictures in one API call, at least not right now.
- Are you sure you looked at the right spot? Keep in mind that there will be a picture posted with a caption, but there will also be a wall post. Maybe you have only changed the photo caption and it´s not visible on the wall. Take a look at the picture directly.

That being said, according to the API reference, you should get more than just "OK", you should get the post id in the result. i´d file a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: Second: yes, I changed only caption, but even directly in picture stays old info. I tried even change picture itself (by url parameter in edit call) - facebook says "OK" and picture stays old.

Comment: according to the api reference, you should get more than just "OK", you should get the post id in the result. i´d file a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/